# What kind of mathematical object is an auto-encoder?

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders

If a fully connected neural net is a function, then what sort of mathematical object is an auto-encoder?

Comment: A very reductionist answer is that an autoencoder is still just a function: it is the composition of the encoder and the decoder, both of which are also just functions

Comment: tongue-in-cheek: _everything_ is a set

Answer (score 1):

An auto-encoder is also a function. Specifically, it's the composition of two functions: an encoder $f$ and a decoder $g$. These functions are related such that $f(x) = z$ and $g(z) \approx x$.

It's tempting to think about $f$ and $g$ as inverses. However, variational auto-encoders or auto-encoders using a bottleneck do not have an exact inverse relationship because an exact reconstruction of an input is not possible using when using random sampling or encoding through a bottleneck.